# Error. Cannot connect to database: SQLSTATE[HYT00]

Tags: php, linux, pdo, sqlsrv

I am getting the following error when trying to connect to my Microsoft SQL Server database using the default port number:

```
Error. Cannot connect to database: SQLSTATE[HYT00]: [unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired
```

This is the PHP code I am using to connect to the database:

```
<?php

class DB_Connect {
    private $db;

    function construct() {
    }

    public function connect() {
        require_once 'String.php';

        try {
            $this->db = new PDO('sqlsrv:Server=$server,1433; Database=$db', $user, $pass);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            return "Error. Cannot connect to database: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}

?>
```

I am 100% sure that the credentials are correct since they are workign when I run the script on localhost using xampp.

What I have done till now:

- Installed the pdo drivers on the linux machine
- Installed the obdc drivers on the linux machine
- Installed the sqlsrv drivers on the linux machine

[image]

This is the configuration I am using on the server:

PHP Version 7.0.30 connecting to SQL Server 2017 hosted on Gearhost.

Can anyone please shed a light on what might be wrong?

Comment: I think just need to change single quote to double quote  $this->db = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=$server,1433; Database=$db", $user, $pass);

Comment: still same error

Comment: Can you connect to SQL Server 2017 hosted on Gearhost with SQL Server Management Studio with the same server name and credentials?

Comment: Yes sure of course I can. It works from SQL server

Comment: I think that problem may be connected with SQL Server TCP/IP dynamic ports configuration. I'm sorry, but I can't reproduce your scenario (I haven't LINUX machine). I think that this link is useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48651225/cant-get-sqlsrv-pdo-to-connect-to-remote-sql-server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the issues were 2:

1. First of all, the drivers were not installed correctly. I needed to install the drivers through PECL. This is how I installed them on Redhat Cent OS 7:

Install PHP:

```
sudo su
wget https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
wget http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm
rpm -Uvh remi-release-7.rpm epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
subscription-manager repos --enable=rhel-7-server-optional-rpms
yum-config-manager --enable remi-php72
yum update
yum install php php-pdo php-xml php-pear php-devel re2c gcc-c++ gcc
```

Install Prerequisites

```
sudo yum-config-manager --enable rhel-server-rhscl-7-rpms
sudo yum install devtoolset-7
scl enable devtoolset-7 bash
```

Install PHP Drivers for SQL Server

```
pecl download sqlsrv
tar xvzf sqlsrv-5.2.0.tgz
cd sqlsrv-5.2.0/
phpize
./configure --with-php-config=/usr/bin/php-config
make
sudo make install
```

Install Apache and restart the service

```
sudo yum install httpd
sudo apachectl restart
```

**--EDIT--**

You can alternatively download the prebuilt binaries from the Github project page, or install from the Remi repo:

```
sudo yum install php-sqlsrv php-pdo_sqlsrv
```

2. In my case I also had to open the firewall connection from the server the database. You check if this is necessary, run sqlcmd from Terminal to connect to the database. If you get a network error with the correct credentials, then you know you've got a firewall problem.

Hope this helps anyone who is struggling connecting to a Linux server to SQL Server.

Comment: No need to install from pecl, if you use "remi" repository, the php-sqlsrv package provides the needed binary.

Comment: I'll include it as an edit in my answer. By the way well done for your library!  You've done a great job!

Answer (score 0):

Can you use this here?

```
try{
    $db = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server,1433=$server;dbname=$db;charset=utf8","$user","$pass");
    $query=$db->prepare("Some SQL String Here");
    $query->execute();
}catch(PDOException  $e ){
    echo "Error: ".$e;
}
```